# Angular VideoJs VR import problems

Tags: angular, three.js, video.js

Probably a stupid question, however.

I'm kinda new to Angular and I'm currently experiencing a few problems trying to use VideoJs VR.
While VideoJs works fine, when trying to use VR for a 360deg Video following error comes up in console:
(( video.es.js:97 VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: three_examples_js_effects_VREffect_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default.a is not a constructor ))

[Screenshot: Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjdqo.png)

This is how I included the VideoJs files:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'videojs-vr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-player',
  templateUrl: './video-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-player.component.scss']
})
export class VideoPlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  player: videojs.player;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.player = videojs('videojs-vr-player');
    this.player.mediainfo = this.player.mediainfo || {};
    this.player.mediainfo.projection = '360';
    this.player.vr({projection: 'AUTO', debug: true, forceCardboard: false});
  }

}
```

edit_1:

These files and probably more do not exist in Three, is the solution downgrading Three? I will try that and close my question if thats the case.

node_modules/videojs-vr/dist/videojs-vr.es.js::

```
import VREffect from 'three/examples/js/effects/VREffect.js';
import OrbitControls from 'three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

edit_2:

So I'm quite stupid, the files are existing, videojs-vr has got it's own node_modules with this specific outdated three version.

Comment: So... it's resolved?

Comment: No, still the same problem. Couldn't find a solution, not even after a whole day of googling.

Comment: What if you try different import? `import * as VideoJs from 'videojs-vr';`

Comment: I just tried it out, I also tried a few different ways, I got the the point where everything initialized as it should, but then the exact same error came up as bevor.

Comment: Probably the best step for now would be to create a live example/server where we could see the results :) It would be easier to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I looking for an alternative now, since videojs-vr seems to be just highly incompatible with my setup, maybe it's just outdated. Do you by chance now an alternative? Ideally with motion controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a last attempt of trying to fix it if found this: https://fmoralesdev.com/2019/10/23/using-external-js-files-in-angular/
so yes it works now, i just had to include it properly.

Thanks for helping @Gytis TG